# How do i apply conditional formatting in xlswriter in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I have the following code i want to apply conditional formatting on the PNL  column as > 0 green and red if < 0.
there are multiple sheets in the file and each sheet has 2 dataframes qw and qua, all of them have a PNL column.

I could not figure out how to do it. can someone help.

```
etfc = [r'D:\Development\Output',]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Q_0405.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for et in etfc:
    for entry in os.scandir(et):
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith('.csv'):
            df = pd.read_csv(entry.path, index_col=False,)
            
            start_row = 0
            start_col = 0
            
            qw = []
            for i in gp:
                sd = df[(df[i] == True)]
                if sd.shape[0] > 0:
                    qw.append({'INDX':i,'PNL': pnl(sd) ,'WR': calc(sd) ,})

            pd.DataFrame(qw).to_excel(writer, startrow=start_row, startcol= start_col, index = False, sheet_name = f'{index}_{j}')

            start_col += 5

            qua = []
            for qu in quar:
                sd = df[(df[qu] == True)]
                if sd.shape[0] > 0:
                    qua.append({'DP':qu,'PNL': pnl(sd) ,'WR': calc(sd) })

            pd.DataFrame(qua).to_excel(writer, startrow=start_row, startcol= start_col, index = False, sheet_name = f'{index}_{j}')

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

Conditionnal Formatting is very well explained in the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_conditional_format.html#ex-cond-format) of [xlsxwriter](/questions/tagged/xlsxwriter).

I will show you the general logic with [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) (*based on your the format of your inputs*) :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_col_to_name

def make_df():
    data = np.random.randint(-10, 11, size=(5, 5))
    cols= np.random.choice(["COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "PNL"], replace=False, size=5)
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

def format_pnl(worksheet, df, col_idx):
    col_name = xl_col_to_name(col_idx)
    worksheet.conditional_format(f"{col_name}2:{col_name}{len(df)+1}",
                                 {"type": "cell",
                                  "criteria": "<=",
                                  "value": 0,
                                  "format": format1})
    
    worksheet.conditional_format(f"{col_name}2:{col_name}{len(df)+1}",
                                 {"type": "cell",
                                  "criteria": ">",
                                  "value": 0,
                                  "format":format2})

with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx") as writer:
    workbook = writer.book
    format1 = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "#FFC7CE", "font_color": "#9C0006"})
    format2 = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "#C6EFCE", "font_color": "#006100"})
    
    for i in range(3):
        df = make_df()
        sheet_name = f"Sheet {i+1}"
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
        format_pnl(writer.sheets[sheet_name], df, df.columns.get_loc("PNL"))
```

Output :

[image]

[image]

[image]